# Zend_Controller Following PEAR Naming Convention

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-controller

I am developing a web-app using zend framework. I like how all the autoloading works however I don't really like the way Zend_Controller names the controllers by default. I am looking for a way to enable zend_controller to understand my controller class named Controller_User stored in {$app}/Controller/User.php . Is there anyway I can do this with least amount of extra code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a subclassed dispatcher ( quoted from http://cslai.coolsilon.com/2009/03/28/extending-zend-framework/ )

```
class Coolsilon_Controller_Dispatcher 
    extends Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard { 
    public function __construct() { 
        parent::__construct(); 
    } 

    public function formatControllerName($unformatted) { 
        return sprintf( 
            'Controller_%s', ucfirst($this->_formatName($unformatted)) 
        ); 
    } 

    public function formatActionName($unformatted) { 
        $formatted = $this->_formatName($unformatted, true); 
        return strtolower(substr($formatted, 0, 1)) . substr($formatted, 1); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly not a step-by-step answer, but I believe you can accomplish what you want by subclassing the standard dispatcher class, and making a few changes to the functions that deal with the controller directory and controller objects. [ZF Ref Guide - Subclassing Dispatcher](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.dispatcher.html#zend.controller.dispatcher.subclassing)